# Ionic push notification in ios

Tags: ios, ionic3

I had added platform iOS 4.5.4 ,installed pod , pod setup ,then in iOS folder installed pod install

Then I try to add phonegap push plugin..but it's not install on my mac but folder added in plugins folder please guide me

After I try to build  error occurs like below:

fatal error: ‘google/protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h’ file not found

## import “google/protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h

Comment: did you try installing protobuf?

Comment: Yes protobuf also installing along with pod install command but in build time  fatal error:  
                         ‘google/protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h’ file not found.             Error occurs